# CSS - mysterious padding with :after & :before

Tags: css

I'm creating a new link style (turning it into a button really) for an old site I'm working on and getting a mysterious padding issue when using :before and :after elements combined with overflow:hidden on the main a element. I have no idea what it could be. Check out the video to see what I mean: https://youtu.be/5sWIxoZdW88

Here's the code I'm using for this element.

```css
.d-button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #f16768;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 200;
}
.d-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.d-button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -87px;
  top: -53px;
  z-index: -99;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.d-button:hover:before {
  right: -57px;
  top: -53px;
}
body {background:gray}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="d-button">Let's Build</a>
```

I'm just looking for clues as to why this is happening. In my Codepen mockup it's fine, it just doesn't make sense to me why overflow:hidden would be adding this padding at all. Help?

Comment: It seem to be working fine. what browser are you getting the issue on?

Comment: Works fine on Chrome and Safari for me.

Comment: If it works fine in the code you're showing here, that doesn't help at all. Can you post a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the issue?